# Identity Framework seed method does not save newly created user when called from Global.asax.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am trying to seed an "admin" account in Identity framework during application start up. The majority of our application is not set up through code-first Entity framework models, so I need to do this without extending one of the IDatabaseInitializer classes. I am using the same database as these database-first models.

This is an ASP.NET MVC 5 application.

In `Global.asax.cs`, I have the following relevant code.

```
using (var context = new IdentityContext(EnvironmentSettings.Current.DatabaseConnections.CreateDbConnection("Extranet").ConnectionString))
{
    context.SeedAdminAccount(EnvironmentSettings.DefaultAdminAccount.UserName, EnvironmentSettings.DefaultAdminAccount.Password).Wait();
}
```

The connection string is an Azure SQL server. The username is an email address, and the password is a string of characters, including a bang.

The class IdentityContext looks like this.

```
public class IdentityContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    public IdentityContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(connectionString);
        Initialize();
    }

    void Initialize()
    {
        Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
        Database.SetInitializer<IdentityContext>(new CreateInitializer());
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("IdentityUser", "dbo");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("IdentityRole", "dbo");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("IdentityUserClaim", "dbo");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("IdentityUserLogin", "dbo");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("IdentityUserRole", "dbo");
    }
}
```

`context.SeedAdminAccount()` is an extension of `IdentityContext`. It looks like this.

```
public static class IdentityContextExtensions
{
    public static async Task SeedAdminAccount(this IdentityContext identityContext, string username, string password)
    {
        var userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>(identityContext));

        //var user = await userManager.FindAsync(EnvironmentSettings.DefaultAdminAccount.UserName, EnvironmentSettings.DefaultAdminAccount.Password);
        var user = await userManager.FindAsync(username, password);

        if (user != null) return;

        user = new IdentityUser() { UserName = username };

        var role = new IdentityUserRole { Role = new IdentityRole(Role.Admin) };
        user.Roles.Add(role);

        await userManager.CreateAsync(user, password);

        identityContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

And lastly, `CreateInitializer` looks like this (although it is not called).

```
public class CreateInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<IdentityContext>
{
    protected override async void Seed(IdentityContext context)
    {
        var user = new
        {
            EnvironmentSettings.DefaultAdminAccount.UserName,
            EnvironmentSettings.DefaultAdminAccount.Password
        };

        await context.SeedAdminAccount(user.UserName, user.Password);

        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

Okay, so with all of that out of the way, here's what works:

1) Application startup successfully creates an instance of `IdentityContext`.

2) Identity framework creates the correct tables with the modified table names.

3) `SeedAdminAccount()` is called with the correct parameters.

4) `userManager.FindAsync()` does not find the user (because it doesn't exist).

5) `SeedAdminAccount()` continues to each statement in its body and returns successfully.

Here's where I'm stuck:

1) Although it appears that my seed method is working correctly, no rows are saved to the `IdentityUser` table, or any other Identity framework tables.

2) If I use the same code from a controller action, a user is created and stored in the `IdentityUser` table successfully.

What am I missing here? Am I using the wrong context during application start up? Is there some sort of exception happening that I can't see?

Comment: Try opening up SQL Profiler and watch what query is sent to the database during `identityContext.SaveChanges();`

Comment: Oh cool, I didn't there was an SQL Profiler. I will check that out. I figured out what my issue was, despite the hours of head-to-desking. I'm going to post my answer soon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Being at a complete loss, I decided to check the return value of `userManager.CreateAsync()`. I noticed the Errors field was non-empty, with the error being "The name specified contains invalid characters".

Turns out, I forgot to overload `UserValidator` to use my `EmailUserValidator` class in the `SeedAdminAccount()` method.

I also changed how I'm storing roles. This is what my seed method looks like now.

```
public static void SeedAdminAccount(this IdentityContext identityContext, string username, string password)
{
    var userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>(identityContext));
    userManager.UserValidator = new EmailUserValidator<IdentityUser>(userManager);

    var user = userManager.Find(username, password);

    if (user != null) return;

    SeedUserRoles(identityContext);

    user = new IdentityUser() { UserName = username };

    var result = userManager.Create(user, password);

    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, Role.Administrator);
    }
    else
    {
        var e = new Exception("Could not add default account.");

        var enumerator = result.Errors.GetEnumerator();
        foreach(var error in result.Errors)
        {
            e.Data.Add(enumerator.Current, error);
        }

        throw e;
    }
}

public static void SeedUserRoles(this IdentityContext identityContext)
{
    var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(identityContext));

    foreach(var role in Role.Roles)
    {
        var roleExists = roleManager.RoleExists(role);

        if (roleExists) continue;

        roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole(role));
    }
}
```

Comment: I spent also a lot of time trying to figure out why the user is not created :) Instead of just checking the return value. Maybe throwing an exception would have been more appropriate in this case.

Comment: Thanks, helped me to figure out my problem: I've tried adding a user with a password that did not fullfil the password requirements, so the user was not created at all without any notice.